# jquery nextall first get id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the id of the next input field when user exit the input field:

```
$("input").blur(function(){
var theid = $(this).attr('id');
var thefield = $(this).nextAll('input').first().attr('id');
alert(thefield);
});
```

Currently it returns undefined.
The HTML code is:

```
<table><tr>
<td>Number</td><td>Name</td>
<tr><td>1 <input type='text' name='deltagernummer[]' value='' size='6' id='r0' tabindex='1' /></td>
<td><input type='text' name='deltagernavn[]' value='' id='rr0' tabindex='-1' /></td></tr>
<tr><td>2 <input type='text' name='deltagernummer[]' value='' size='6' id='r1' tabindex='2' /></td>
<td><input type='text' name='deltagernavn[]' value='' id='rr1' tabindex='-1' /></td></tr>
</table>
```

What is the problem?

```js
$("input").blur(function() {
  var theid = $(this).attr('id');
  var thefield = $(this).nextAll('input').first().attr('id');
  alert(thefield);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Number</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <tr>
      <td>1 <input type='text' name='deltagernummer[]' value='' size='6' id='r0' tabindex='1' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='deltagernavn[]' value='' id='rr0' tabindex='-1' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2 <input type='text' name='deltagernummer[]' value='' size='6' id='r1' tabindex='2' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='deltagernavn[]' value='' id='rr1' tabindex='-1' /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Nextall()` goes through siblings, your inputs have no siblings.

```
$("input").blur(function(){
    var theid = $(this).attr('id');
    var thefield = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('input').attr('id');
    alert(thefield);
});
```

```js
$("input").blur(function() {
  var theid = $(this).attr('id');
  var thefield = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('input').attr('id');
  alert(thefield);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Number</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <tr>
      <td>1 <input type='text' name='deltagernummer[]' value='' size='6' id='r0' tabindex='1' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='deltagernavn[]' value='' id='rr0' tabindex='-1' /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2 <input type='text' name='deltagernummer[]' value='' size='6' id='r1' tabindex='2' /></td>
      <td><input type='text' name='deltagernavn[]' value='' id='rr1' tabindex='-1' /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: As long as the next `<tr>` does have an input, this works. If it doesn't, this will fail. Just a suggestion, as the OP never mentioned of such case. :)

Answer (score 6):

`.nextAll()` scans for siblings. Although your `<input>`s are in the same level, *they're not siblings*. To "visualize", here's pseudo-HTML:

Child and child's sibling:

```
<parent>
  <child>
  <childs-sibling>
</parent>
```

Your case:

```
<parent>
  <descendant>
    <input>
  </descendant>
  <descendant-sibling>
    <totally-unrelated-to-input>
  </descendant-sibling>
</parent>
```

What you can do is climb up to the `<tr>` level, succeeding rows, get all inputs, get the first one and then get the id.

```
var id = $(this)
    .closest('tr')           // Get to the row level
    .nextAll('tr')           // Get all succeeding rows
    .find('td > input')      // Find the inputs. You may adjust the selector.
    .eq(0)                   // Get the first input
    .attr('id');             // Get its id, if any
```